# Uncaught TypeError: d.AmMap is not constructor error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

Uncaught TypeError:  d.AmMap is not a constructor at Object.d.makeChart(amcharts.js.1)

What is the reason for this kind of error

Comment: Please provide additional information, like the code you've written and relevant context. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NeGKKQ this is my code.  It's working fine in codepen.io but not in my application

Comment: @TadasAntanavicius

Comment: What setup are you using? create-react-app? This sounds like a problem with the build setup since you can't reproduce on codepen.